# gcloud app deploy command error INVALID_ARGUMENT: WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gcloud

I try to convert work from appengine-web.xml file to work with app.yaml file in google app engine project, so I created app.yaml file and put it in main folder of project.
when I try to deploy my project with "gcloud app deploy" command
I get error
INVALID_ARGUMENT: WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime
if I run "gcloud app deploy path/appengine-web.xml"  command
the deploy is work fine
what i need to to convert to work with app.yaml file?
additions info
my project write in java8
my project write in eclipse

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One **Java Application** that will be deployed in App Engine must have a file named **appengine-web.xml** in its WAR, in the directory WEB-INF/.

I verified the **gcloud app deploy** command [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy)  and it seems that for Java 8 you need to run :

```html
gcloud app deploy ~/my_app/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
```

That is the one that you are running.

On the other hand, I found this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only#organizing_your_files) (**for Flexible** ) that mentions how to  organize your files in case that you want to use the app.yaml for java 8

Answer (score 0):

As the documetnatyion indicated that,[for Java8 Standard apps, you must add the path to the appengine-web.xml file inside the WEB-INF directory. gcloud app deploy skips files specified in the .gcloudignore file see gcloud topic gcloudignore for more information](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy).